# Test then() inside of a promise API call jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am trying to test a function which is an api call / promise so I can check state inside `then` using jest but cant seem to figure out what to do. I have tried mocking the file and the function to return a promise but getting an error `TypeError: (0 , _dataAccess.fetchBundlesFromApi) is not a function` I've tried following the docs on jests website and also the many different answers from stack overflow but none seem to work. Here is the code I want to test. I want to be able to call that and then say if okay check state or if error do something else. below is the code i am trying to do and the mocking that I have tried.

```
getLatestPrices = params => {
    const { updateBundles } = this.props;

    fetchBundlesFromApi(params)
      .then(({ data: { bundles } }) => {
        updateBundles(bundles);
        this.setState({ showUpdatingPrices: false });
        window.TemplateCalculator.reload();
      })
      .catch(() => goToUrl(bundlesUrl));
  };`
```

`fetchBundlesFromApi` is `import { fetchBundlesFromApi } from '../../../../dataAccess';` which is an axios call:

```
const fetchBundlesFromApi = params => axios(`${bundleRoute}/bundles${params}`);

export { fetchBundlesFromApi };
```

This is the mocking I have tried.

```
jest.mock('../../../../dataAccess', () => ({
      fetchBundlesFromApi: new Promise(resolve => resolve({ data: mockBundles })),
    }));
```

I have also tried these websites:
 https://binarapps.com/blog/test-ajax-calls-in-react-component-lifecycle.
[Jest/Enzyme Error: "Method 'setState' is only meant to run on a single node. 3 found instead."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767157/jest-enzyme-error-method-setstate-is-only-meant-to-run-on-a-single-node-3-f/52767973#52767973)
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous

Comment: Please edit your code, `goToUrl` function and `bundlesUrl`, where do they come from?

Comment: ‘goToUrl’ is just a function that is imported to do a redirect. ‘bundlesUrl’ is also just a imported variable which is just a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out I had to import my api call function like so:

```
import { fetchBundlesFromApi } from '../../../../dataAccess';
```

As that function was using axios I had to mock that. I did that like so:

```
jest.mock('axios', () => jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: mockBundles })));
```

The in my test I made it async and I could await that function response.

```
const fetchedBundles = await fetchBundlesFromApi(
  'params',
);
```